# how to restore the windows clipboard after deleting it

Tags: windows, restore, clipboard

I found a rare link on Google on how to remove the WIN+V Windows Clipboard, but now I cannot find that same link that also had instructions on how to restore it back.

At the time of removal, I suspected an issue that was causing data replication within the clipboard as items would double, triple and even higher quantity paste when using it.

I since solved that issue it was a macro on my Razer Chroma KB, that had been inadvertently activated by my daughter and programmed to do the command several times over.

Does anyone know how to restore the Windows 10 WIN+V Clipboard functionality if you removed the actual application folder itself?

It was located within the windows folder as a big long random folder name, but without that web link, i don't have the restore instructions.

Thanks :)

Comment: Ramhound - i appreciate the lookout, but leave my question alone please :)

Answer (score 0):

If you removed the Clipboard folder, then the contents are gone.

I use Clipboard and there is no way I can see to restore contents.

To restore the Clipboard App, please see

[Add Clipboard](https://sevenitblog.com/2020/04/09/restore-windows-10-store-app-via-powershell/)

> C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsStore_12004.1001.1.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml
> The last step will be running the full install command with the route
> we got and the manifest via powershell:
>
> Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsStore_12004.1001.1.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml"
> -DisableDevelopmentMode

.

You might also be able to add the App from the Store (not certain).

.

If you run into major issues, you may need to try a **Windows 10 Repair Install.**

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

**Start with Keep Everything.**

If all the above does not work, then the OS or Windows User Profile is more seriously damaged and you need to back up and reinstall Windows

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141828/discussion-on-answer-by-john-how-to-restore-the-windows-clipboard-after-deleting).

Answer (score 0):

Repair Windows. There is no need to install the clipboard, since it's built into Windows, and the OS "knows" how to fix itself.

- The most straightforward repair uses [Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM) and System File Check (SFC)](https://www.techbout.com/repair-windows-system-files-using-sfc-dism-12162/)"

  - Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `cmd`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> to get a CMD prompt.
  - Type `sfc /scannow` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and *wait*, perhaps a half-hour or more, for SFC to *complete*.
  - Type `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and *wait*, perhaps a half-hour or more (again), for SFC to *complete*.

That likely will replace the deleted clipboard folder and fix the issue. However, if that fails, rather than replacing the folder manually, download the latest Windows ISO for your OS and *reinstall* Windows, keeping files. **N.B.:** It is a *very* good idea to make a complete drive image *before* reinstalling Windows, lest something go wrong!

Comment: i literally did all of that - and it did not fix it. 

Im not worried about losing my OS Install, i do a annual reinstall of my OS anyways, and I am at that point. 

"

There is no need to install the clipboard, since it's built into Windows, and the OS "knows" how to fix itself.

Contrary to that, there is a way to actually DELETE it,  if i could find that weblink again.  It literally stops WIN+V from even working.  its a folder, buried deep.

Comment: You may need to reinstall Windows to fix the issue.  I added that to my answer